# JQuery traversing the dom: Not finding correct location

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using JQuery to hide and show a div when the user presses a button. The button however is located in another div. I have to traverse up the tree and I thought I did it correctly, but I keep getting an error. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. The problem is I could use ...

```
$( "button.add" ).click(function() {
    $('.more-reports').toggle( "slow" );
  });
```

The problem with the above is that this goes through a loop that creates multiple instances of these divs. So using it, works, but will open all instances. See my adjustments below(that also don't seem to work.

Here is my page...

```
%section.report-library
  .container
    %br
    - @attachments_by_type.each do |type, attachments|
      - recent_attachment = attachments.shift
        %article.report-container
          .report
            %ul.inline
              %li
                %h3= type
                %dl
                  %dd
                    Uploaded By
                    %span= recent_attachment.recruiter_name
                  %dd
                    &#8226;
                  %dd
                    = recent_attachment.created_at.strftime("%D %r")
                  %dd
                    &#8226;
                  %dd
                    %button.add#button View previous attachments(This is the button)
                %p 
                  = recent_attachment.description    
              %li
                %a.btn.primary{:href => "#{recent_attachment.url}"} Download      
          .more-reports{:style => "display: none"}(This is the div I am hiding and showing)
            - attachments.each do |attachment|
                %dl
                  %dd
                    Uploaded By
                    %span=attachment.recruiter_name
                  %dd
                    =attachment.created_at.strftime("%D %r")
                  %dd
                    %a{:href => "#{attachment.url}"} Download
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$( "button.add" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil('article.report-container').next('.more-reports').toggle( "slow" );
  });
```

I have even tried .parent().parent().parent().parent() with different amounts of .parent(). None of those seem to work.

generated html

```
<section class='report-library'>
      <div class='container'>
        <br>
        <article class='report-container'>
          <div class='report'>
            <ul class='inline'>
              <li>
                <h3>Type B</h3>
                <dl>
                  <dd>
                    Uploaded By
                    <span>Brad Martin</span>
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    &#8226;
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    05/22/14 09:24:55 PM
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    &#8226;
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    <button class='add'>View previous attachments</button>
                  </dd>
                </dl>
                <p>
                  Description
                </p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class='btn primary'>Download</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class='more-reports' style='display: none'>
               <dd>(Ignore the indentions here. placed in as dummy text)
                    Uploaded By
                    <span>Brad Martin</span>
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    &#8226;
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    05/22/14 09:24:55 PM
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    &#8226;
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    <button class='add'>View previous attachments</button>
                  </dd>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class='report-container'>
          <div class='report'>
            <ul class='inline'>
              <li>
                <h3>Type A</h3>
                <dl>
                  <dd>
                    Uploaded By
                    <span>Brad Martin</span>
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    &#8226;
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    05/22/14 08:53:52 PM
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    &#8226;
                  </dd>
                  <dd>
                    <button class='add'>View previous attachments</button>
                  </dd>
                </dl>
                <p>
                  Description
                </p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class='btn primary>Download</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class='more-reports' style='display: none'>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: can you share the generated html - also it should be `closest('.report-container')` or `closest('.report')` instead of `.parentsUntil()`(you have missed the `s`)

Comment: It should be `parentsUntil` not `parentUntil`.  Also the `next` call is not going to find anything in this case because `article.report-container` does not have any sibling.  The `.more-reports` is a sibling of `.report`, isn't it?

Comment: HTML is up and I did have parents in my app, I just copied it without it for some reason.

Comment: tried `$( "button.add" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil('.report').next('.more-reports').toggle( "slow" );
  });` still getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it; since `.more-reports` is a child of `.report-container` you can traverse to `.report-container` using `.closest()`. `parentsUntil()` will match multiple parents and may not be suitable. `.children()` ensures you're going in one level - no further.

```
$(function() {
    $( "button.add" ).click( function() {
        $(this).closest( '.report-container' ).children('.more-reports').toggle( "slow" );
    });
});
```

Comment: ah ok, I thought closest only moves down the dom. And I'm not sure why I didn't think of using children. I guess it's just really late. Thank you so much!